# How can i delete something from cloud firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to delete a document in my firestore database

i'm using a listview to list some things of my data base, the items of this listview have a delete button, what i want is: when the user presses the delete button, this thing gets deleted from the list and from the firestore, there what i'm trying:

[image: in case of any of you need a picture of the database]

this is my entire activity to do this:

```
class RigBuilderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var botaoAddPc: FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var pcName:EditText
    lateinit var infoButton:FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var pcListView: ListView

    companion object{
        const val TAG = "RigBuilderActivity"

    }

    var pc = arrayListOf<PC>()

    val pcAdapter = PcAdapter()

    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rig_builder)
        botaoAddPc = findViewById(R.id.rig_builder_button_add_pc)
        pcName = findViewById(R.id.rig_builder_text_input)
        infoButton = findViewById(R.id.rig_builder_button_info)
        pcListView = findViewById(R.id.rig_builder_pc_list)


        botaoAddPc.setOnClickListener{

            var pc_text :String = pcName.text.toString()
            val computer = PC(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),pc_text)

            db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("PC").add(computer.toHashmapPC()).addOnSuccessListener { task->
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${task.id}")
                Toast.makeText(this,"Pc added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener{ e->
                Log.w(TAG,"Error Adding PC",e)
                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        pcListView.adapter = pcAdapter


        db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("PC").addSnapshotListener{ value, e->

            if (e!=null){
                Log.w(TAG,"Listen failed.",e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            pc.clear()
            for (doc in value!!){
                val pc = PC.fromQueryDoc(doc)
                this.pc.add(pc)
            }

            pcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

    fun getPcName():String{
        return pcName.toString()
    }

    inner class PcAdapter : BaseAdapter() {

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return pc.size
        }

        override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
            return pc[p0]
        }

        override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
            return 0
        }

        override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            val rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pc_item_layout, p2,false )
            val textViewPcName = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pc_name)
            val editButton = rootView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.pc_edit_button)
            val deleteButton = rootView.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.pc_delete_button)

            textViewPcName.text = pc[p0].counter.toString()

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener{


                val ref : DocumentReference = db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("PC").document(pc[p0].getPcId())

                ref.delete().addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Pc deleted with success")
                    Toast.makeText(this@RigBuilderActivity,"Deleted with success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                pcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            editButton.setOnClickListener{

            }

            textViewPcName.text = pc[p0].name
            return rootView
        }
    }
}
```

in case of needing, this is my PC class, i'm just using one of the constructors to test the list and make the delete works:

```
class PC {

    var id:String
    var name : String? = null
    var counter : Long? = null
    lateinit var cpu :CPU
    lateinit var gpu: GPU
    lateinit var motherBoard: MotherBoard


    /**
     * Construtor de teste
     */
    constructor(id:String, name:String?){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
    }


    /**
     * Construtor ainda a implementar
     */
    constructor(id:String, name:String?, cpu: CPU,gpu: GPU,motherBoard: MotherBoard){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.cpu = cpu
        this.gpu = gpu
        this.motherBoard = motherBoard
    }


    fun toHashmapPC() : HashMap <String, Any?>{
        return hashMapOf(
            "id" to id,
            "name" to name
        )
    }

    fun getPcId():String{
        return id
    }

    companion object{
        fun fromQueryDoc(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot):PC{
            return PC(
                documentSnapshot["id"] as String,
                documentSnapshot["name"] as String
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a failure listener to the d elete operation, to see if something gets wrong?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).